# What is the best way to store a large amount of text in a SQL server table?

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to store a large amount of text in a table in SQL server?

Is varchar(max) reliable?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In SQL 2005 and higher, VARCHAR(MAX) is indeed the preferred method. The TEXT type is still available, but primarily for backward compatibility with SQL 2000 and lower.

Comment: How do I write the query for large text? `INSERT INTO VALUES(id, other fields, '<large-text>');`? Or insert the other fields in first then update the entry for the large text field?

Answer (score 20):

I like using VARCHAR(MAX) (or actually NVARCHAR) because it works like a standard VARCHAR field. Since it's introduction, I use it rather than TEXT fields whenever possible.

Comment: Very good point about NVARCHAR; my bad -- I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 6):

Varchar(max) is available only in SQL 2005 or later. This will store up to 2GB and can be treated as a regular varchar. Before SQL 2005, use the "text" type.

Answer (score 3):

According to the text found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ua8h4paLqB8C&pg=PA128&dq=store+a+large+amount+of+text+in+a+table+in+sql+server&ei=4g3dSJHeG4LKigGq4rznDg&sig=ACfU3U21YI3tfNw-0iU5PEpXpKmr2C7t4g), varbinary(max) is the way to go.  You'll be able to store approximately 2GB of data.

Answer (score 3):

Split the text into chunks that your database can actually handle.  And, put the split up text in another table.  Use the `id` from the `text_chunk` table as `text_chunk_id` in your original table.  You might want another column in your table to keep text that fits within your largest text data type.

```
CREATE TABLE text_chunk (
     id NUMBER,
     chunk_sequence NUMBER,
     text BIGTEXT)
```

Comment: This seems very heavy weight; some context as to when this technique is required or appropriate vs nvarchar, and what the costs/benefits are would improve the quality of the asnwer.

Comment: I guess when a text files goes above 2Go you need to split it ?

Answer (score 2):

In a BLOB

BLOBs are very large variable binary or character data, typically documents (.txt, .doc) and pictures (.jpeg, .gif, .bmp), which can be stored in a database. In SQL Server, BLOBs can be text, ntext, or image data type, you can use the text type

text

Variable-length non-Unicode data, stored in the code page of the server, with a maximum length of 231 - 1 (2,147,483,647) characters.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, a design alternative to consider is saving them as .txt file to server and save the file path to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvarchar(max)` to store the whole chat conversation thread in a single record. Each individual text message (or block) is identified in the content text by inserting markers.

Example:

```
{{UserId: Date and time}}<Chat Text>.
```

On display time UI should be intelligent enough to understand this markers and display it correctly. This way one record should suffice for a single conversation as long as size limit is not reached.